# Read CSV and store in two double arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, csv

I want to read a csv file which contains data points i.e X and Y locations. Hence I want to read the CSV file and store it in two arrays X and Y.

I am trying the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void readEntireFile(void);

int main(void) {

    readEntireFile();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void readEntireFile(){
    int ch;
    FILE *fp;  // pointer to a file type
    fp = fopen("/geometrydata.csv", "r"); 
    ch = getc(fp);
    while (ch != EOF){  // keep looping until End Of File
        putchar(ch);    // print the characters read
        ch = getc(fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

With this code I am getting the records in file, however I don't have idea that how to store these record in an array.

Records in file is of following format

```
-3.5,0.00E+00
-3.289729021,0.00E+00
-3.090472028,0.00E+00
```

So I have to store the X as

```
[-3.5 -3.289729021 -3.09.472028]
```

and Y as

```
[0.00E+00 0.00E+00 0.00E+00]
```

Answer (score 0):

For formatted data, I'd recommend `fscanf`:

```
double X[NO_OF_LINES], Y[NO_OF_LINES]; /* NO_OF_LINES refers to the no of lines in your csv file */
int i;
for(i = 0; i < NO_OF_LINES && fscanf(fp, "%lf,%lf", &X[i], &Y[i]) == 2; i++);

if(i != NO_OF_LINES)
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR! %d lines could not be read, success in reading %d lines", NO_OF_LINES, i);

for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    printf("X[%d] = %f, Y[%d] = %f", j, X[j], j, Y[j]);
```

Comment: Thank you. Your concept worked.
I want to sequentially store the data. 97x49 points in the grid. File have data such as First 97 rows corresponds to 1 st Y point, next 97 Rows corresponds to 2nd Y point.
I understand I need two for loops, but with ur code I am not able to implement this concept. Can u elaborate how this can be achieved?

Comment: I did not understand. What's the content of the file?

Comment: @CoolGuy I think OP has a file in which is stored a 97x49 mesh (grid) as 4753 rows of pair of coordinates of points. I guess He wants to recreate the grid structure somehow in memory (2D array of points?).

Comment: @VishalJadhav So, you have a total of 4753 pairs of coordinates arranged in the form of `X,Y` and you want to read them?

Comment: If so, Try `double points[97][49][2]; int i, j; for(i = 0; i < 97; i++) for(j = 0; j < 49; j++) if( fscanf(fp, "%lf,%lf", &points[i][j][0], &points[i][j][1]) != 2 ) goto outsideLoops; outsideLoops: if(i != 97 || j != 49) fprintf(stderr, "ERROR! %d lines could not be read, success in reading %d lines", 97 * 49, (i+1) * (j+1)); for(int m = 0; m < i; m++) for(int n = 0; n < j; n++)printf("points[%d][%d][0] = %f, points[%d][%d][1] = %f", m, n, points[m][n][0], m, n, points[m][n][1]);` Haven't tested ↑ ... May contain errors...

Comment: @CoolGuy
Thank you, it worked. I did some modification.
 double xCord[97][49];
 double yCord[97][49];
 for(j = 0; j < 49; j++)
  for(i = 0; i < 97; i++)
  if( fscanf(fp, "%lf,%lf", &xCord[i][j], &yCord[i][j]) != 2 )
   goto outsideLoops;
 outsideLoops: if(i != 97 || j != 49)
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR! %d lines could not be read, success in reading %d lines", 97 * 49, (i+1) * (j+1));
 for(n = 0; n < j; n++)
  for(m = 0; m < i; m++)
   printf("xCord[%d][%d] = %f, yCord[%d][%d] = %f \n", m, n, xCord[m][n], m, n, yCord[m][n]);